# why is my time/date picker formatting adding minutes?

Tags: javascript, angular, datetime, datepicker, angular-moment

I have both a time picker and a date picker in my template. The values store to my database together as one numeric string, so I have to do a few steps to parse them from one another in the right formats when I interpolate them to my template in the required places on a different page. First I call a formatting function to separate the values and then I run it through an angular-moment pipe to convert the military time to standard 12 hour time.

I noticed that consistently when I pick a time, say 7:00 or 12:00 on the time picker, it will interpolate to my template as 7:08 or 12:08. Why is it adding minutes?

THIS IS HOW I SAVE THE DATE AND TIME TO THE DATABASE

```
constructor(//controllers n stuff) {

//empty event object

      this.event = {
        hostName : "",
        hostId: "",
        hostPhoto : "",
        coverCharge: 0,
        drinkMin: false,
        reimburse: false,
        venue : "",
        guests : 0,
        date : "", 
        time : "",
        city : "",
        eventTime : "",
        createdTime: "",
        volunteers : 0 

      } 
}//close constructor 

addEvent(){

    let authData = OnymosAccess.getAuth(); //GET DATABASE AUTH
            this.event.hostName = authData.userName;
            this.event.hostId = authData.userId; 
            this.event.hostPhoto = authData.userPhoto();
          **this.event.eventTime = new Date(this.event.date + " " + this.event.time).getTime();**
            this.event.createdTime = Date.now();

            let that = this;

                OnymosUtil.addData( //SEND TO DATABASE

        '/events/' + this.event.city + '/' + this.event.createdTime,
                        this.event,

        function optionalSuccessCallback (statusMessage) {
                            console.log(statusMessage);

                            that.saveStatus = "successfully saved";
                         },

            function optionalFailureCallback (error) {

                            that.saveStatus = "failed saving" + error;
                        });
}//end addEvent
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
                    <BR>
                    **{{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}}** 
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col>
                    <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
                    <BR> 
                    **{{ getFormattedTime(event.eventTime,'HH:MM' ) | amParse:'HH:mm' | amDateFormat:'hh:mm A' }}**

                </ion-col>
```

THE GET FORMATTED TIME FUNCTION I RUN THE TIME THROUGH BEFORE I USE MOMENT.

```
getFormattedTime (time, format) {
        var t = new Date(time);
        var tf = function (i) { return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i };
        return format.replace(/yyyy|MM|dd|HH|mm|ss/g, function (a) {
            switch (a) {
                case 'yyyy':
                    return tf(t.getFullYear());

                case 'MM':
                    return tf(t.getMonth() + 1);

                case 'mm':
                    return tf(t.getMinutes());

                case 'dd':
                    return tf(t.getDate());

                case 'HH':
                    return tf(t.getHours());

                case 'ss':
                    return tf(t.getSeconds());

            }
        })
    } // end of getFormattedTime
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ion-col>
     <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
     <BR>
     **{{getFormattedTime(event.eventTime, 'MM-dd-yyyy')}}** 
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
     <ion-icon name="clock"></ion-icon>
     <BR> 
     **{{ getFormattedTime(event.eventTime,'HH:mm' ) | amParse:'HH:mm' | amDateFormat:'hh:mm A' }}**
</ion-col>
```

You have to use `getFormattedTime(event.eventTime,'HH:mm' )`. In your code you are using `getFormattedTime(event.eventTime,'HH:MM' )` MM will return month

`MM`- Months,
`mm` -Minutes

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and try it here. You can check below code snippet. You are using `new Date(this.event.date + " " + this.event.time).getTime()` in code. It working fine. And you can do it `new Date(this.event.date + " " + this.event.time)` directly without `.getTime()` as well.

It seems that you did `'HH:MM'`, instead of `'HH:mm'`. Correct it in code and try it.

```js
function getFormattedTime (time, format) {
        var t = new Date(time);
        var tf = function (i) { return (i < 10 ? '0' : '') + i };
        return format.replace(/yyyy|MM|dd|HH|mm|ss/g, function (a) {
            switch (a) {
                case 'yyyy':
                    return tf(t.getFullYear());

                case 'MM':
                    return tf(t.getMonth() + 1);

                case 'mm':
                    return tf(t.getMinutes());

                case 'dd':
                    return tf(t.getDate());

                case 'HH':
                    return tf(t.getHours());

                case 'ss':
                    return tf(t.getSeconds());

            }
        })
    }
    
    var time=new Date("2017-07-05 07:00").getTime();
    console.log(time);
    console.log( getFormattedTime(time, 'MM-dd-yyyy'));
    console.log(getFormattedTime(time,'HH:mm' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using uppercase `MM` that maps to `t.getMonth()` instead of lowercase `mm` (minutes).

Anyway, since you are using momentjs, I suggest to change your `getFormattedTime` using moment parsing ([`moment(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/) to parse milliseconds) and [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Note that, with my code, you have to use moment tokens (so uppercase `YYYY` for year and uppercase `DD` for day of month)

Here a live example:

```js
function getFormattedTime(time, format) {
  return moment(time).format(format);
}

console.log( getFormattedTime(1499200000000, 'MM-DD-YYYY') );
console.log( getFormattedTime(1499200000000, 'HH:mm') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```